# Accessing an NSMutableArray based on a string search, then writing to the NSLog some of the objects

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to search an NSMutableArray, which has been initialised with calendar events from the event store. I am specifically wanting to search the array for the string "office", which will of been entered in some of the calendar entries for the "location" property. Then l need to write to the NSLog the following specific values from each of the return events:

Event title
Event start time
Event end time
Event location

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No need to try, this is simple question Google it...you will get many answers...

Answer (score 1):

You could use NSPredicate, it is easy and very fast

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"publisher == %@", @"Apress" ];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"publisher containts[cd] %@", @"Apress" ];
NSArray *filtered  = [bookshelf filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score -1):

You would iterate over the array using a for-loop or, better, fast enumeration
catching each string contained in the array and check it for the occurrence of the
substring @"office".

Take a look at fast enumeration: `for (id object in myMutableArray)`
and at NSString's methods for finding substrings like `-rangeOfString:`

You will find the answer to your question using google, apple's docs and
StackOverflow with little effort and a basic understanding of the
programming language...

Comment: Okay, why the down vote? How about leaving a comment?